# SQL to calculate trailing sum based on partial data

Tags: sql

I have a few different footfall sensors across some stores.

Some sensors record footfall every 15min, others every 30min, and others every 60min. Not all stores have all sensors, and some data readings are missing.

The readings of the 60min sensor are the most accurate, followed by the 30min sensor, followed by the 15min.

I have this in a SQL table of the form:

| sensorId | storeId | sensorType | readingTimeStamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15m | 2022-06-01 10:45 | 99 |
| 1 | 1 | 15m | 2022-06-01 11:00 | 51 |
| 1 | 1 | 15m | 2022-06-01 11:15 | 19 |
| 1 | 1 | 15m | 2022-06-01 11:30 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 30m | 2022-06-01 11:00 | 86 |
| 2 | 1 | 30m | 2022-06-01 11:30 | 89 |
| 3 | 1 | 60m | 2022-06-01 11:00 | 115 |

The task is to calculate the footfall in the last 60min every 15 minutes.

The logic is as follows:

1. If the last 60min are available from a 60min sensor use that
2. Else try to use the sum of two 30min sensors
3. Else try to use a 30min and two 15min sensors
4. Else try to use four of the 15min sensors
5. If we are not "on-the-hour" then build the reading starting from the last hourly measure

For example, at 11:45 the "best" way to calculate this is:

60min reading at 11:00 + 30min reading at 11:30 + 15min reading at 11:45 - 30min reading at 10:30 - 15min reading at 10:45

I have some Python code that does this fairly well. But any ideas on how to implement it in SQL?

*PS: this calculation is a business requirement. Also, it can't assume that two 15min readings add up to the 30min reading, etc...

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also have to specify the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many product are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)